# Use of the conjunction "that" to express an intentional consequence

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions, register

First an example; just to make clear what I'm referring to.

> He wrote a note on the calendar, **that** he might remember to call his friend on his birthday.

Meaning:

> He wrote a note on the calendar, **in order** to remember to call his friend on his birthday.

I remember having seen this usage somewhere, but I just wanted to make sure that it was actually correct, or commonly used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is an older variant of **so that**.   It is rarely used in contemporary spoken or written English.

A contemporary speaker is mostly likely to encounter it at church or in a [religious text full of archaisms and formulaic phrases](https://books.google.com/books?id=Lnxarp6MQrEC&pg=PT363&dq=%22that%20they%20might%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihy6ixvojeAhUPU98KHaStCSsQ6AEIVjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22that%20they%20might%22&f=false)

For example:

> That they might be saved, He sent ...

Today it is in an elevated register, so it might be used in a  brochure, say, seeking to strike a tone of refined elegance and long-standing tradition:

> That our guests might enjoy their stay in unparalleled luxury, the hotel has not just one but two Michelin three-star restaurants to choose from.